# How to awk pattern over two consecutive lines?

Tags: awk

I am trying do something which I guess could be done very easy but I cant seem to find the answer. I want to use awk to pick out lines between two patterns, but I also want the pattern to match two consecutive lines. I have tried to find the solution on the Internet bu perhaps I did not search for the right keywords. An example would better describe this.

Suppose I have the following file called test:

```
aaaa
bbbb

   SOME CONTENT 1

ddddd    
fffff


aaaa    
cccc

    SOME CONTENT 2

ccccc    
fffff
```

For example lets say I would like to find "SOME CONTENT 1"

Then I would use awk like this:

```
  cat test | awk  '/aaa*/ { show=1} show; /fff*/ {show=0}'
```

But that is not want I want. I want somehow to enter the pattern:

```
  aaaa*\nbbbb*
```

And the same for the end pattern. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: If you want the filter to match more than one lines, you probably have to set the Record Separator through the `RS` variable

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense, `aaaa` and `bbbb` are on the same line - how would that match against `aaaa*\nbbbb*` (also, I am sure this regex does not do what you think it does)? Please provide a more minimal example and explain which patterns are triggers and separate the records from eachother. As @user000001 points out, you probably need to set `RS` to a sane value.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I think that was due to wrong formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk  '/aaa*/ {f=1} /bbb*/ && f {show=1} show; /fff*/ {show=f=0}' file
bbbb

   SOME CONTENT 1

ddddd
fffff
```

If pattern1 is `aaa*` then set flag `f`
If pattern2 is `bbb*` and flag `f` is true, then set the `show` flag

---

If you need to print patter1 the `aaa*`?

```
awk  '/aaa*/ {f=$0} /bbb*/ && f {show=1;$0=f RS $0} show; /fff*/ {show=f=0}' file
aaaa
bbbb

   SOME CONTENT 1

ddddd
fffff
```

Answer (score 1):

If every record ends with `fffff`, and `GNU awk` is available, you could do something like this:

```
$ awk '/aaa*\nbbbb*/' RS='fffff' file
aaaa
bbbb

   SOME CONTENT 1

ddddd
```

Or if you want just `SOME CONTENT 1` to be visible, you can do:

```
$ awk -F $'\n' '/aaa*\nbbbb*/{print $4}' RS='fffff' file
   SOME CONTENT 1
```

Comment: This only works with `gnu awk` due to multiple characters in `RS`

Comment: Right, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for two patterns and checkd that they were consecutive using line numbers, having line numbers lets sed insert a line between them, well after the first line/pattern.

```
awk '$0 ~ "Encryption" {print NR} $0 ~ "Bit Rates:1" {print NR}' /tmp/mainscan | while read line1; do read line2; echo "$(($line2 - 1)) $line1"; done > /tmp/this



    while read line 
    do 
    pato=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d' ') 
    patt=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d' ') 
    if [[ "$pato" = "$patt" ]]; then 
       inspat=$((patt + 1)) 
       sed -i "${inspat}iESSID:##" /tmp/mainscan 
       sed -i 's/##/""/g' /tmp/mainscan 
    fi 
    done < /tmp/this
```